# How to delete Online Accounts

Tags: online-accounts

Just ugraded to 20.04 LTS. Ubuntu user for 12 years.

I have no use for all the online accounts and following the directions below to delete or uninstall does not work.

```
Open the Activities overview and start typing Online Accounts.

Click on Online Accounts to open the panel.

Select the account which you wish to remove.

Click the - button in the lower-left corner of the window.

Click Remove in the confirmation dialog.
```

No button appears in the lower left or anywhere else.

I would not even have signed on with a google account or started a Ubuntu account if it were not for asking these questions.

I do not want them I do not want to see them and I want them gone from "MY" system.

Please tell me what the command is or how to get rid of these online accounts.

Answer (score 0):

### **You might not have any accounts set up.**

The `-` button is for removing an online account.  It will not be there if no online accounts are configured.

If you haven't set up any online accounts, then you aren't using the feature.

If you don't want to use the feature, you could just ignore the "*Online Accounts*" category in the settings menu in the same way that some users can ignore "*Printers*" or "*Universal Access*".  Ubuntu includes these options for people who want to enable them, but you don't need to use a printer, magnifier, or connect to an online account to use Ubuntu.